# Firebase Phone Authentication is giving E.164 format errors for European 9 digit phone numbers and some 8 digit phone numbers

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have been using firebase phone authentication for sometime now and it works well for 10 digit phone numbers such as (ex. US +14567893456). I have been trying to extend the same auth service interface for phone numbers that are not 10 digit. When I enter the phone number according to E.164 format, if the number is less that 10 digit , I am getting following error.

> The format of the phone number provided is incorrect. Please enter the phone number in a format that can be parsed into E.164 format. E.164 phone numbers are written in the format [+][country code][subscriber number including area code].

Now, I understand the E.164 format, my code works perfectly for countries with 10 digit phone numbers. I have also tried using the PhoneNumber package from pub.dev to parse my input into e164 format, which is basically same as I would normally parse without the package. Can someone please explain to me, the reason for this error?

NOTE: If someone from Firebase team is reading this, I suggest please include more documentation for cases like this. All i could find on firebase website was example for US phone numbers. In reality phone numbers can be 15 upto 15 digits.

Comment: Example Phone numbers:
+33486055040 this for France with a country code of +33.
+31502663245 This is a Dutch number with a country code of +31.

I am getting the same error for both.